# Installation Step Failed (installing the system) - Kali Linux

Tags: osx, system-installation, virtualbox, kali-linux

I am trying to install Kali Linux on a Virtual Machine using Virtual Box on an OS X host.

The only issue is I get this error:
[image]

Here are logs of my errors:

- [hardware-summary](http://pastebin.com/rWsXkp6K)
- [partman](http://pastebin.com/HdhHKdCR)
- [syslog](http://pastebin.com/E154bGTX)

I had my hard drive formatted as `/` `/temp` `/users`etc.

How would I install Kali linux in VirturalBox with an OS X Host? The Image I used was `kali-linux-1.1.0a-amd64.iso` and I also checked that the sha1 hash was valid.

Small print:
The log information was found by using the 'web server' and have been uploaded to pastebin since this post would have been too big. The log names I have given is what was on the web server

Comment: `"Jun 10 16:20:13 main-menu[714]: (process:8928): tar: write error: No space left on device"` Is the disk image you provided for the VM big enough?

Comment: I made a 10GB dynamically allocated HDD. The 'actual' space is 373MB. So there is plenty of space left on the virtual HDD. Also what file was that message in?

Comment: if you use one part '/' then 12 gb is enough (min recommended 16gb); but if you want separate partitions , make sure the /usr part have more than 8gb !    ^ i'd kali on multi-parts and it was working well with the following scheme ( / => 4 gb; /usr => 10 gb ; /var => 4 gb ; /tmp = swap = RAM-memory ; /opt => 4gb ; /home => as u like ; )

Comment: Recommending closure because the log files are no longer available, so the question is no longer clear.

Comment: @roaima You can close it if you like, I fixed this along time ago and forgot to post it here. I some reason can't close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this along time ago, thought I posted it on here. All I needed to do was to install the OS as one partition, for some reason it formatted the other directories the wrong size.

Answer (score 30):

Increase your virtual hard disk space to 12 GB or more.
I faced similar issue and the above resolved my issue.

Comment: I found out that is was when I installed it there was not enough room for one of the partitions (I formatted it as /home / /etc (or whatever it was). By installing it onto a whole partition, it worked fine.